# Codeigniter drop down class overriding Twitter Bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work. In my form I am passing a php echo form_dropdown for the select option values.

When I add the twitter bootstrap class it makes a button around the dynamic dropdown form or it disappears.

I am trying to have a twitter bootstrap button that includes my dynamic dropdown options.

Here is what I tried:

*note: the $class is in there as a 2nd parameter to pass twitter bootstrap. It does not have to be there if I can have a twitter bootstrap class without passing 2nd parameter.

```
<div class="row">

<div id="myselect2" class="col-md-12 form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-3">
     <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-3">

         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
              <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>

              <?php echo form_dropdown('myselect', $options, $class); ?>
          </ul>
          <hr/>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I would like:

http://postimg.org/image/igdkamxzt/0f73e2b5/

Here is what I have:

http://postimg.org/image/8v3pbwxkd/8bd64bd1/

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work.

Like what?

Assuming you're using `Bootstrap 3.x` which it seems you are, follow the examples [given here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns). Example:

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It's hard to help you without seeing code. Also maybe try not to generate a CI dropdown first, but install hard-code it with the Bootstrap example.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but as I had the same problem I will answer here.
My Problem was that I accidentally switched those two lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
```

Problem then was that you have to import jquery befoore bootstrap js file ;)
And yet another two hours wasted ;)